# StackMob & UITableView lags

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, stackmob

I have strange behavior with UITableView and StackMob SDK last version.

I'm try to show list of users in the table. My request code like in [this tutorial](https://developer.stackmob.com/ios-sdk/read-into-table-view-tutorial) by StackMob:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"username" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *results) {
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    self.objects = results;
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    NSLog(@"An error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}];
```

and then after each calling of

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

SDK sends request to the server

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"username"];
    return cell;
}
```

Other links I found: [1](http://support.stackmob.com/requests/2888), [2](http://www.verious.com/qa/uitable-view-scrolling-madness/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535613/uitableview-scrolling-madness)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the slowness is that every new cell creation has to wait on a connection to the server to fetch 'username'. I think the best solution is to update to the 2.0 SDK (if you are not already using it). And enable the cache, see [here](https://developer.stackmob.com/ios-sdk/offline-sync-guide) for details of how. That way the initial fetch will populate the cache with the username objects and each call to the NSManagedObject in cellForRowAtIndexPath will then not cause a network request.